# Moving inline Javascript to External Combined Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

Hi There I am busy moving all my inline javascripts to a combined.js file. In my header I have the code below. I am working in wordpress.

The code below makes a slider function on my page. I have already moved the bulk part of the javascript to a combined js file.

```
<br /><br /><script>(function($){jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {$DragOrientation: 3, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {$Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, $ChanceToShow: 2 }}); function ScaleSlider() { var windowWidth = $JssorUtils$.$GetWindowSize(window).x; if (windowWidth) jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(windowWidth); else window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);}
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

};})(jQuery);
            
                
                
                    
                    
                    
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
        Slider Javascript
        (function($){jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container')})(jQuery);

I have tried moving these parts to the Js file, but do not use `document.Write` to write the html part to the page, instead I have kept the html part in the page, and was hoping that I can get the JavaScript function to execute once the custom.js is loaded and this will render the html as intended.

I have copied this part to the combine.js file.

```
(function($){jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {$DragOrientation: 3, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {$Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, $ChanceToShow: 2 }}); function ScaleSlider() { var windowWidth = $JssorUtils$.$GetWindowSize(window).x; if (windowWidth) jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(windowWidth); else window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);}

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

};})(jQuery);

and also this part

```
(function($){jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container')})(jQuery);
```

but I am not having luck

any ideas why this script executes correctly inline, but not when I include it into the js file will be appreciated, and also any advice on how to implement the call from the external combined.js file to make this work will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `slider1_container` div rendered first before you can use it, try putting your JS call on the footer or wrap this:

```
(function($){jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container')})(jQuery);
```

like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  (function($){jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container')})(jQuery);
});
```

so it waits for the document to be ready before you execute the JS.

Comment: Hi David - very good tip, However my external script is being loaded <script async></script> when I take out the async the script works, when I place it back again it does not

Answer (score 1):

If you have all that JS in an external file combine.js, just include it in the HTML using a script tag like this:

```
<script src="<url of combine.js>" type="text/javascript" />
```

The javascript will then run at the point in the HTML that the script tag is included, just like the script tags you have in your example with the javascript code in the body of the tag.

N.B. you'll probably want to put the script tag at the [bottom of the page](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) for best performance.

That's it, should just work. If it doesn't, check the javascript console for errors.

Comment: Hi, This is exactly how I have it, when I place the script in asynchronous loading it breaks... when I remove it, it works again

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by asynchronous loading? When you load in an external script using the above tag, it will block the page until the script is downloaded and executed. That's pretty synchronous, and it's why for performance it's best to put it at the bottom, after the rest of the DOM is loaded. And I don't understand how it can work when you remove it!? Do you mean it works when you revert to how it is in your example?

Comment: Having seen your comment on the other answer I see you're using the async attribute to load the script asynchronously. If you want to do this, make sure your functions are only run after the appropriate divs have been parsed in the HTML. You can use David Lee's jQuery(document).ready solution for this or just declare named functions in the global namespace and call them inside script tags in the appropriate place in your HTML. Or, alternatively, don't use async and place the tag at the bottom of the body. There will likely be no performance difference noticed either way in this case.